# Pandas explode columns based on daterange

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a dataframe which appears as following:

```
Col1    6/13/2020-6/15/2020 6/16/2020
A1      2.3                 1.65
A2      1.4                 1.4
A3      1.3                 1.3
```

I want to explode the columns when daterange is present which is represented by presence of `-` in the column name.

Desired result is the following:

```
Col1    6/13/2020   6/14/2020   6/15/2020   6/16/2020
A1     2.3          2.3         2.3         1.65
A2     1.4          1.4         1.4         1.4
A3     1.3          1.3         1.3         1.3
```

I am not sure how to explode it across the columns.

Comment: I think you'll need to have multiple dataframes here -- by creating the new columns manually and having this restructured into a new dataframe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We still do `explode`

```
s=df.set_index('Col1').T.reset_index()
s
Out[49]: 
Col1                index    A1   A2   A3
0     6/13/2020-6/15/2020  2.30  1.4  1.3
1               6/16/2020  1.65  1.4  1.3
s['index']=[pd.date_range(x.split('-')[0],x.split('-')[-1]) for x in s['index']]
s=s.explode('index').set_index('index').T.reset_index()
s
Out[52]: 
index Col1  2020-06-13 00:00:00  ...  2020-06-15 00:00:00  2020-06-16 00:00:00
0       A1                  2.3  ...                  2.3                 1.65
1       A2                  1.4  ...                  1.4                 1.40
2       A3                  1.3  ...                  1.3                 1.30
[3 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: that -1 is cool. Oneliner is probably something like `(df.set_index('Col1').T
   .rename(lambda x:pd.date_range(x.split('-')[0], x.split('-')[-1]))
   .reset_index() 
   .explode('index')
   .set_index('index').T)`

Answer (score 2):

Convert non datetimes columns to index and then in list comprehension create new DataFrame with [`numpy.broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) and last join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('Col1')

dfs = [pd.DataFrame(data=np.broadcast_to(df1.iloc[:,[i]].to_numpy(), 
                                         shape=(len(df1), len(pd.date_range(s, e)))), 
                   index=df1.index, 
                   columns=pd.date_range(s, e))
      if pd.notna(e) 
      else pd.DataFrame(df1.iloc[:,[i]].to_numpy(), 
                        index=df1.index, 
                        columns=[pd.to_datetime(s)]) 
      for i, (s, e) in enumerate(df1.columns.str.split('-', expand=True))]

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
print (df)
      2020-06-13  2020-06-14  2020-06-15  2020-06-16
Col1                                                
A1           2.3         2.3         2.3        1.65
A2           1.4         1.4         1.4        1.40
A3           1.3         1.3         1.3        1.30
```

If possible overlapping:

```
print (df)
  Col1  6/13/2020-6/16/2020  6/16/2020
0   A1                  2.3       1.65 <- 6/16/2020 is overlap
1   A2                  1.4       1.40
2   A3                  1.3       1.30

df1 = df.set_index('Col1')

dfs = [pd.DataFrame(data=np.broadcast_to(df1.iloc[:,[i]].to_numpy(), 
                                         shape=(len(df1), len(pd.date_range(s, e)))), 
                   index=df1.index, 
                   columns=pd.date_range(s, e))
      if pd.notna(e) 
      else pd.DataFrame(df1.iloc[:,[i]].to_numpy(), 
                        index=df1.index, 
                        columns=[pd.to_datetime(s)]) 
      for i, (s, e) in enumerate(df1.columns.str.split('-', expand=True))]

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).sum(level=0, axis=1)
print (df)
      2020-06-13  2020-06-14  2020-06-15  2020-06-16
Col1                                                
A1           2.3         2.3         2.3        3.95
A2           1.4         1.4         1.4        2.80
A3           1.3         1.3         1.3        2.60
```